# OneDrive ignores "delete" operations performed on other device

Tags: onedrive

I've been using OneDrive for years; Dropbox before. Every time I deleted some file or folder on any of my devices (or on-line, via web page) this information was propagated to all other devices once they become on-line and started syncing files. As an effect, file was deleted on all of these devices.

For past week or so I'm 100% positive that OneDrive is no longer working this way.

Right now, if I delete some file (either on computer A or via webpage) that still sticks on computer B and computer C, when any of these computers (B or C) is turned on, OneDrive simply ignores that delete operation, finds that a file stored locally is missing and starts to uploading them again.

I have or had thousand of files that went through following scenario:

- deleted on computer A (or via OneDrive webpage),
- confirmed via webpage that it is removed from OneDrive,
- computer B turned on; file re-uploaded,
- confirmed via webpage that it is back on OneDrive,
- removed from computer B (or via OneDrive webpage),
- confirmed via webpage that it is removed from OneDrive,
- computer C turned on; file re-uploaded again,
- confirmed via webpage that it is back on OneDrive for third time,
- removed from computer C (or via OneDrive webpage),
- **only then file is removed permanently**.

I managed to confirm above scenario on three different PCs, all running Windows 7.  I cannot verify, if it happens on mobile devices, because I'm not using OneDrive on them.

Is this some kind of bug or recent change in OneDrive? Is there any way to stop this behavior?

Using OneDrive or any other cloud-based file-syncing service that causes me to delete each file three times, because I have it synced on three different PCs -- is simply pointless and out of question.

Comment: Since this is more about the file synchronization functionality of OneDrive rather than an issue using the web application, your question is probably better off at [su].

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because computer B is turned off while the file is deleted on A,so when B  is turned on, and OneDrive checks the files, it is seen as newly created, since according to OneDrive, it wasn't there earlier (you deleted it). There's not much you can do to fix this, but I would suggest moving to something more versatile, such as Git (GitLab offers privacy)

Comment: As I wrote in my question, this seems to be either a bug or recent change. I'm pretty sure that for past years OneDrive was working as supposed and as other similar software do. I.e. delete operation on one of the devices was correctly propagated to other devices and scenario described by me in my question was not possible before. In the light of this, your answer seems to be more like a comment.

Comment: You don't provide confirmation of a bug or change in functionality. And you don't provide much solution for working over this (if exists) other than "use the better software". Which is out of question, as explained in my comment under question itself. This is only to explain, why I'm reluctant to upvote or accept your answer.